# Matplotlib: matplotlibrc file ignored after seaborn import

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, qtconsole

I have a custom `matplotlibrc` file with matplotlib configuration options, following the procedure [here](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html).  When I first start up Jupyter QtConsole (through the terminal, if that matters), the file is being read—plots use the options I've set, such as dashed grid lines:

```
%matplotlib inline

plt.plot([1, 2, 3])
Out[2]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x9d2fe80>]
```

[image]

The `matplotlibrc` file is here:

```
mpl.matplotlib_fname()
Out[4]: 'C:\\Users\\my_username\\.matplotlib\\matplotlibrc'
```

But then if I import seaborn:

```
import seaborn as sns
```

plots then switch to seaborn style:

```
plt.plot([1, 2, 3])
Out[6]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0xceb9cc0>]
```

[image]

**Is it possible to retain the original plotting style while also importing seaborn?**  I'd like to use its capabilities, such as `seaborn.heatmap`, but not its styles.

Comment: Do any of those files import `seaborn`? That's the seaborn style.

Comment: Great catch, yes, that's what's going on.  Edited my question because that leads to another issue entirely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of:

```
import seaborn as sns
```

Use:

```
import seaborn.apionly as sns
```

You get the API, without the styling. The developer included this option for people who wanted Seaborn's features without its custom appearance.